# iOS Simulator Crash in App with Embedded Binary

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, simulator

I'm having a strange issue and wondering if anyone knows what is going on. In Xcode 6.2, if you follow these steps:

1. create a new workspace
2. create a new iOS > Application> Single View Application project in
   the workspace
3. create a new iOS > Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework
   project in the workspace
4. add the framework as an embedded binary in the app
5. build and run the app on any 8.2 simulator and then stop it
6. launch the app from within the simulator

Every time you try to launch the app from within the simulator (not running it from Xcode, but actually clicking on the app icon inside the simulator) the app crashes on startup. The only thing I see in the system log is:

```
Apr  3 20:04:53 MacBook com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.6B002DFB-FE6C-4295-BA22-742E4CEE2B6D.launchd_sim[61494] (UIKitApplication:com.test.TestApp[0xcb1d][61787]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5  
Apr  3 20:04:53 MacBook.local SpringBoard[61507]: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.test.TestApp[0xcb1d]' crashed.  
Apr  3 20:04:53 MacBook assertiond[61511]: assertion failed: 14C1514 12D508: assertiond + 14743 [849F745E-3AAA-3638-91FF-892312A54F42]: 0x1
```

Does anyone know if this is by-design or if embedded binaries work correctly? I'm hesitant to add an embedded binary to my app if the app always crashes in the simulator.

Thanks!
- Tom B.

Comment: Hi @tombz, do you have any solution now ?

Comment: The issue is that a framework can only be built for one platform, but there are two platforms it will need to run on: iOS Simulator and iOS Device. When you drag the framework into the “Embedded Binaries” section, you are likely dragging the iOS Device version. When you Build and Run for the Simulator, Xcode modifies the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable when launching the app so it can find the version built for the Simulator. When you launch your app manually, it cannot find the version of the framework built for the Simulator since the iOS Device version was included in the app bundle.

Comment: To resolve this issue, you need to bundle a Simulator version of your framework when your app is built for the Simulator, and bundle an iOS Device version of your framework when your app is built for iOS Device. When building for the Simulator, drag the Simulator version of your framework into Embedded Binaries. When building for iOS Device, remove the Simulator version from Embedded Binaries and add the iOS Device version of your framework.

Comment: Hi @tombz , thank you for your answer. I have forgotten to add one of my framework to Embedded Binaries.